# Ragged Right linebreaking, such that the last line is fullest, and the first most empty

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

using `\raggedright` roughly speaking will result in linebreaking when ever there is not enough space on the line to put the next word.
This in turn results in all lines, except the last, being mostly full.

I want to achieve the opposite.
I wish for the last line to be full, and the first line to be partially empty.

In the example below I have achieved this for the second heading using manual line breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\myheading}[1]{{\textbf{\raggedright #1}}\\}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \myheading{This is the first heading}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.\\
    \bigskip

    \myheading{This is\\ the last heading}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\myheading}[1]{{\bfseries\raggedright\parfillskip=-\rightskip #1\par}}% why not define as a heading?
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \myheading{This is the first heading}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The above ensures that on the last line there is no stretch glue added so it is always fully justified. This may not be desired in all cases, specifically if the paragraph is single line you probably want a flush left setting and also if the last line is short you may prefer it to be ragged rather than over-stretch to justify.  You can add `\hspace*{\fill}` at the end of the text in these cases, but below is a more complicated version but sets the heading in a box so that it can remove the last line of the paragraph and in the case the paragraph had just one line, or the natural length of the last line is less than 80% of the line width, then the last line is set at its natural width, flush left and the justified last line is discarded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\myheading}[1]{%
\xdef\tmpdepth{\prevdepth\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox0\vbox{{%
\tmpdepth
\bfseries\raggedright\parfillskip=-\rightskip #1\par
\xdef\tmpdepth{\prevdepth\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox0\lastbox
\setbox2\hbox{\unhcopy0}%
\nointerlineskip
\ifnum\prevgraf=1 \box2 \else
\ifdim\wd2<.8\wd0 \box2 \else
\box0
\fi\fi
}}%
\unvbox0
\tmpdepth
}% why not define as a heading?
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \myheading{This igs}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,


    \myheading{This is longer igs}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,


    \myheading{This is much longer and covers several lines igs}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,

    \myheading{This is much much longer and covers several lines igs}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,

    \myheading{This is much much longer ad covers sevezzzzzl lines gs}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Sometimes I am amazed at how easy it is to do the weirdest things with LaTeX!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Actually, this very thing (breaking paragraphs into lines, using the elegant box-glue-penalty model) is, in some sense, the core/heart of TeX, so it makes sense that this would be easy. :-)

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain how it works a bit more?

Comment: Doesn't quiet work right,  if the heading is only on one line.
try:
`\myheading{short head}`   It is not ragged, it is kinda justified (via interword spacing)

Comment: I am messing around with it, `\hfill` doesn't help at all.
(I'm trying `ragged2e` but that doesn't work ideally for `\myheading{medium len head}` which it breaks unnecessarily

Comment: Indeed that fixes single lines, but it breaks all multilines back to the original behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, but given (unstated) my goal is to avoid doing it by hand (I was thinking of manually line breaking every  heading)...

Comment: Oh, I was worrying this was going to be a `\setbox` kinda problem.

Comment: @LyndonWhite white space before last line fixed

Comment: Right now what i am doing is using `ragged2e` for 
`\newcommand{\myheading}[1]{{\bfseries\setlength{\RaggedRightParfillskip}{-\RaggedRightRightskip}\RaggedRight #1\par}}`
Which seems to just be yielding generally pleasing looking headings to me.

Comment: @LyndonWhite doesn't that still force one-line paragraphs to be fully justified?

Comment: One line paragraphs shouldn't be fully justified, they should aligned right. It seems to make them aligned right.

Comment: @LyndonWhite ah yes of course only if you don't mind tex screaming `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) ` at you? (it's worth locally setting `\hbadness=10000` to silence those warnings. so the _specification_ of the last line is that it is fully justified but your code (like mine) removes `\parfillskip` so there is no stretch at the end of the line, however with standard raggedright that allows the interword space to over-stretch but ragged2e's version fixes interword space so it does not stretch or shrink, ...

Comment: @LyndonWhite so they appear as if the last line is set natural width but actually tex is trying to justify it but has no stretchable so it gives up, produces the output you want, but declares it is badness 10000 (infinitely bad). Still silencing the warnings and accepting the result is reasonable course of action

Comment: @LyndonWhite to see the same thing with my initial simple version add `\spaceskip=.3em` to the settings